# Gradually appear/fade in HTML element as you scroll down/up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, effect

I'm trying to create the following effect:

1. Unless you've scrolled down 100 px or more, you won't see the element (e.g. a *div*).
2. When you've scrolled 100 px, and keep scrolling, in a smooth way the *div* element will appear, and it'll have shown up completely when you've scrolled 200 px.

This means that it just won't appear like a transition effect. But rather, if let's say you scroll 150 px, you can see the *div* element with transparent effect (50% since it at 100 px it starts to fade in and at 200 px it has completely shown up). If you scroll 175 px, you can see the div even more. And if you reach 200 px and continue scrolling down, the *div* will stay visible.

Same back up: if you scroll up it'll gradually disappear.

This is mainly for an Android page: a header in the top of the screen will appear gradually and then it will stay at the top (using `position: fixed;`).

Only last thing I have to clarify is that making this effect will mean that the css will constantly change: at 120 px the `opacity`  is going to have `0.2` (20% visible), at 155 of `0.55`, at 183 of `0.83`.

Note: it's possible! I've seen it before! =)

Comment: What have you tried to date? What is your HTML markup/CSS? SO is not here to give you a complete solution, rather assist with specific coding problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of no evidence to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: It has already been solved by Rami.Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand you right then try this:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    var top = $( window ).scrollTop( );
    var opacity = (top-100)/100;    
    fixedElement.css("opacity",opacity);
});
```

**DEMO:**

https://jsfiddle.net/8zhLgjsj/1/